# How to show loading status while loading drop down / select list with the values from backend database ? Angular 1, bootstrap and spark

Tags: angularjs

I want to load the dropdown/select form field using values from the backend. The query for the backend is from a text field in the same form. I have this working partially where I am able to:

- Pass the query value from the text field in the same form
- Query the database and get the list
- Populate the dropdown with values fetched from the database

However I am not able to show the loading status while the data is being fetched, heres my code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-show="colorLoading">
    Loading, please wait...
    <!-- can also put gif animation instead -->
</div>

<select class="form-control" ng-options="color as color for color in colorOptions" name="color" ng-init="color = color || colorOptions[0]" ng-model="color" ng-click ="loadColors(productId)" ng-hide="colorLoading" required></select>
```

JS:

```
   $scope.loadColors = function(val) {
       console.log("PRODUCT ID " + val);
       $scope.colorLoading = true; 
       $http.get('/api/v1/bugdb/getColors?productId=' + val).success(function (data){
            console.log(data);
            $scope.colorOptions = data;
            $scope.colorLoading = false; 
        }).error(function (data, status) {
            $scope.colorLoading = false; 
            console.log('Error ' + data)
        });         

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-mousedown.

Change

```
ng-click ="loadColors(productId)"
```

To

```
ng-mousedown = “loadColors(productId)”
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `*ngIf` condition in template to show the loading div while data being fetched.

```
<div *ngIf="colorLoading;else content">loading...</div>
 <ng-template #content>
    <select class="form-control" ng-options="color as color for color in colorOptions" name="color" ng-init="color = color || colorOptions[0]" ng-model="color" ng-click ="loadColors(productId)" ng-hide="colorLoading" required></select>
 </ng-template>
```

In this above example, when colorLoading marked as true, template renders the loading div. Once colorLoading marked as false. It will search for content div and load it.

For more info refer [this](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)